# In Python3 iterate a dictionary without copying values to local variable, but just a reference or pointer?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I understand that to iterate efficiently through a dictionary without making a new copy of the whole dictionary:

```
for k,v in iter(d.items()):
    print("k={} v={}".format(k,v))  # or do whatever. This is just placeholder code.
```

Q: Is there some way that python3.5.4 can give me the v value directly, as a pointer to it or a reference, rather than copying the value to local variable v in my for loop?  This can help me if v is a large array because each v is a numpy array that has 10^5 or 10^6 elements or even more in my app, and my iterator loop has like millions of iterations.  In other languages I have used references and pointers, but I have not used them (to my knowledge) in python3.5.4.

Thanks for sharing your know-how.

Update:

Here is some numpy python code that I used to prove that v is not a local copy but is a reference to a numpy array.  this is very good news for me. This confirms what the winning answerer said. Thanks to the winning answerer and all other commenters claiming the same.  I am happy about it!! Thanks again to all who participated.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([8,6,7,5,3,0,9])
d = {}
d["mouse"] = x
for k,v in iter(d.items()):
    v[1] = 2
print(d)
```

The dictionary now contains a new value in one array location. This means the v[1]=2 line was operating on the original array not a local copy of the array.

Comment: a view is not an iterator, right?

Comment: Anyway, let's focus on the question of getting a reference instead of a copy.

Comment: V is a local variable containing a COPY of ONE item's value, I would wager. So no, v is not a reference.

Comment: @GeoffreyAnderson To help convince yourself of this, run `d = {1: list(range(100000000))}` in the interactive interpreter.  It should take a few seconds to build a big list.  Then try `for k, v in d.items(): print(len(v))`.  That will execute instantly, because a new list is not being created.

Comment: Vote trading is against Stack Overflow rules.

Comment: You may find this article helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Answer (score 5):

`for k, v in d.items(): ...` performs two assignments. In each iteration, `k` is assigned to the key and `v` is assigned to the value of the next (key, value) tuple yielded from the iterator over `d.items()`.

Assignment never copies data, so

> Is there some way that python3.5.4 can give me the v value directly, as a pointer to it or a reference, rather than copying the value to local variable v in my for loop

is already happening.

In addition, in Python3.5 the return value of `dict.items` is a very memoery efficient view of the data in the dictionary. In summary, you already have everything you asked for.

Comment: >Assignment never copies data, so<   Do you have a link to support your claim? I would dearly like what you say to be true, but it's not true just because you claim it.

Comment: @GeoffreyAnderson [certainly](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html#h_assignment)

Comment: @timegeb, I just ran an experiment with numpy arrays and it proved you are correct that it was a reference.  I am convinced and thank you.  Nice. I could post up my experimental code somewhere. Not sure where to put the code though.

Answer (score 0):

An example to support timgeb's answer above.

```py
test = {
    'outer' : {
        'inner_1' : 1,
        'inner_2' : 2
    }
}


for k_0, v_0 in test.items():
    for k_1, v_1 in v_0.items():
        v_0[k_1] = 0
        
print(test)
```

Output:

```py
{'outer': {'inner_1': 0, 'inner_2': 0}}
```